# Sum Of Binary Numbers (using C Style Strings)

Tags: c++, binary, addition

I'm working on a program to add two binary numbers together from command line inputs (argv, argc). It is also left justified.

For example: $a.out 0 1 returns 1, $a.out 10 1 returns 11 etc.

I'm using a function to do the addition and I know 100% my issue lies within my function, but I cant figure out what I'm doing wrong. When I add two binary numbers that have a carry of '0' at the very from it doesn't print the '1' in the sum. I have another issue where some sums are printed in reverse but not others. If anyone could point me in the right directions on what I'm doing wrong, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Examples of the sums that are wrong:

```
$a.out 10 10
00      // should be "100"
$a.out 11 11
01      // should be "110"
$a.out 100 100
000     // should be "1000"
$a.out 110000 1
100011 // should be "110001"
```

My function:

```
bool add (const char aug[], const char add[], char sum[])
//aug is the first command line binary number (argv[1]), add is the second (argv[2])
{

    char carry = '0';
    int ag = strlen(augend) - 1;
    int ad = strlen(addend) - 1;
    int max = ((ag > ad)? ag : ad);

    for (int i = 0; i <= max; ag--, ad--, i++)
    {
         char augDigit = (ag < 0)? '0' : augend[ag];
         char addDigit = (ad < 0)? '0' : addend[ad];

         switch (augDigit + addDigit + carry)
         {
             case '0' + '0' + '0':
                 sum[i] = '0';
                 carry = '0';
                 break;
             case '1' + '0' + '0':
                 sum[i] = '1';
                 carry = '0';
                 break;
             case '1' + '1' + '0':
                 sum[i] = '0';
                 carry = '1';
                 break;
             case '1' + '1' + '1':
                 sum[i] = '1';
                 carry = '1';
                 break;
          }
    }    
    return true; 
    // returns true if the sum is less than 36 digits but I'll deal with         
    // that once i fix this issue
}
```

Comment: Since you have known inputs that fail, pick one of these inputs, create a small program that exercises that one input, and then step through the program with a debugging tool with an eye out for where the program deviates from your expectations.  Deviation is either a bug in the program or an error in your expectations. Either one needs to be resolved before continuing.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i <= max;` looks like it could be an overflow. `i` is allowed to range  [0,`max`] when C++ addressing typically ranges from [0, `max`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two reasons: reason number one is that you're storing the result in reverse order, and number two, you're not accounting for the last carry. If the last sum carries out, you have to append another `'1'` to the result.

Comment: Thank you. I reverse the sum array and that fixed one of my issues.  Would you be able to point me in the right direction of adding the '1' to the beginning? Should I shift the elements in the ray down one and make sum[0] = '1' if the first element is a 0?

Comment: @jtb123 after the loop, before returning and before reversing the result, check if `carry` is `'1'`. If it is then append it to the result.

Comment: You're a blessing. Thank you